# VBScript to Zip all files in a folder/sub-folders while preserving the original file name

Tags: vbscript, zip

I'm wondering if someone has a script to zip all the files in a folder and it's sub-folders while maintaining the original filenames? So basically for every file within the folder, I would want a corresponding zip file created. I've never used VBScript before so I'm not sure how this can be done and would take a me quite a while to figure it out. I would then remove all instances of the original files.

Answer (score 2):

You can download zip utilities like [GNU zip](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zip.htm), pkzip, rar, winzip etc. find one that comes with command line capability. then you can just create a batch using for loop (to loop over you files) and zipping them one by one. check `ren /?` , `del /?` for renaming and deleting files.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is exactly what the gzip utility does. It compresses the data into a .gz file with the original file name and extention. By default when it succeeds it removes the original file. unzipping is the opposite process.